# Server Error while file upload in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

When i upload a file of size 35MB or more it gives

```
Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

and if i upload a file of size 25MB or less then that it works fine. This issue occurred only when i deploy it on a server if i run it on my local system it works perfectly. One thing i want to tell that i have override httpruntime setting in my web.config and its have

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3145728" executionTimeout="1200" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

what may be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days i found answer to my question and the issue is that IIS7 have maximum file upload limit which is 30000000 Bytes which is around 29MB

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, there is an alternate solution that can be enabled at the site level rather than server-wide.

source: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits

Comment: After solving this issue i have written a blog post at http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2011/02/request-filtering-module-is-configured.html